Azure CLI - Bash script with variables not working
I'm trying to run a simple Bash script file from Azure CLI in Azure portal. But it is throwing error as "Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'" . What is the correct syntax for the below Azure CLI command with varible for Bash?
#!/bin/bash
rgName="my-train-rg01"
serverName="test-db-svc-primary"
#echo $rgName
#echo $serverName
#echo  "Hellow Wrold!"
az sql db list --resource-group $rgName --server $serverName



why the question has been down voted? can you please explain what is wrong with the script?

The command seems to be correct. Can you post the result of type az ?

@Philippe please find the result.  azureuser [ ~ ]$ type az
az is /usr/bin/az

This is a wild guess, but does the bash script have DOS/Windows-style line endings?

Not my downvote, but if you don't get a syntax error, your syntax seems to be valid. The question would need additional debugging details before we can tell you what's wrong. See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

@GordonDavisson I'm trying to run the script from azure portal CLI from windows system.

@MarsRoverII If the script file was created on Windows, it's probably in the wrong format and needs to be converted to unix format to work right.

Try to put quotes like az sql db list --resource-group "$rgName" --server "$serverName"

@Philippe with the quotes, got the same error.

If you're getting a bad request, as an alternative you can use below script:
$test=az graph query -q "resources`
| where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases'`
| extend serverName = tostring(split(id, '/', 8)[0])`
| where serverName contains 'servername' and resourceGroup contains 'resource-Grpp_name'"
$rith=$test|ConvertFrom-Json
$rith.data

Output:

In bash:
rith_q="resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.sql/servers/databases' | extend serverName = tostring(split(id, '/', 8)[0]) | where serverName contains 'servername' and resourceGroup contains 'resource-Grpp_name'"
test=$(az graph query -q "$rith_q")
rith=$(echo "$test" | jq '.data')
echo "$rith"

Output:

